# How to use PerformanceObserver to detect and fix longtask?

Tags: javascript, performance, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, web-performance

Recently i came across the PerformanceObserver,
(https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/performance-observer
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceObserver)

It provide option for tracking longtask, I added in my code and got some longtask, result looks like this

[image: Long Task]

There is no information about where it happening and what triggers it. Please help me to understand what is long task and how to fix it.

Thanks

Comment: I had the same problem, looks like this feature is not yet completely implemented. Actually the TaskAttributionTiming should provide informations about where the source of the long running task is. The specification is still a draft: https://w3c.github.io/longtasks/#taskattributiontiming